# Disable a specific column in GWT Grid

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to disable a specific column in gwt data grid ..something like

```
myColumn.setDisable(true);
```

My purpose is to prevent the selection of a `SelectionCell` in the datagrid.That should be non editable ..

any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

A. You can [create a custom cell](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells) which would render  element set to disabled under certain conditions. This is the closest to what you want, but it may also be a little confusing to your users - they may think your table is broken.

B. You can remove column with SelectionCell and insert column with TextCell in its place.