# How to disable(not remove) a column in celltable of gwt

Tags: gwt

i am new to GWT.I know tablename.removeColumn(columnname) can be used to remove the column, but instead of removing i want to disable it. Can anybody please help
thnx in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable a specific column in GWT Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040594/disable-a-specific-column-in-gwt-grid)

Comment: @chad Nouis i want to disable it ..not change the column type

Comment: What do you mean by `disable`. Can you provide an example or some additional clarification?

Comment: @chad Nouis what i mean is the field should be present but the user should not be able to write anything in it.

Comment: Is this column always disabled, for all users? Or depending on some condition the column might be enabled or disabled? The reason I'm asking is because when specifing a column you can specify if it is editable by providing the correct column type (`TextInputCell` is editable, `TextColumn` is disabled/not editable). So if the column is for all purposes disabled then just use TextColumn, if there is a condition though it's a little more complex, and I need the condition in order to provide some code.

Comment: The link provided by @ChadNouis is correct. Your question is solved by that answer. That's the gwt way of disabling a column, by providing the correct column type. So this `i want to disable it ..not change the column type` is incorrect. They are the same thing essentially.

Comment: @alkis i want to disable the column depending upon some condition.Actually i am fetching a url by:
      
 String url = Window.Location.getHref();
  boolean value = url.contains("xyz");

based on value i want to enable or disable my column.

Comment: not really..i ended creating a new component and calling that based on the url...thanks for the efforts anyways mate (y)

Comment: In order for the thread to be considered closed, you could provide an answer of your own and mark that. This way, the answer you found can be used by others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new component that has the columns that i want and called that component based on the url

```
String url = Window.Location.getHref(); 
boolean value = url.contains("xyz");
if(value)
{
  component.setEnable(true);
 }
else{
  componentprevious.setEnable(true);
     }

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this, but an easy and clean way to do it is the following :

```
public static class CustomTextInputCell extends TextInputCell {
    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        String url = Window.Location.getHref(); 
        boolean isEditable = url.contains("xyz");

        if (isEditable)  //Condition if editable or not
            super.render(context, value, sb);
        else if (value != null) {
            sb.appendEscaped(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The render method will be called every time this cell is rendered. So every time it will check if the condition is met to be enabled or not. 
This allows you to keep all the functionality of an editable cell but disable it easily when the condition is met.

You use it like this

```
Column<YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, String> column = new Column<YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, String>(new CustomTextInputCell()); 
cellTable.addColumn(column , "YOUR_HEADER_HERE");
```